# Cannot open a tab in a specific browser using webbrowser module Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-webbrowser

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.get('opera').open('www.google.com')
```

The code above returns an error "webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser", I want the code to open a tab specifically in Opera, which isn't my default browser.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so turns out the problem was that webbrowser module wasn't seeing any of my browsers, I checked that by doing `print(webbrowser._browsers)` and it came back empty. This is the fix that worked is making a new controller like this

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.register("l", None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser("Path"), preferred=False)
controller = webbrowser.get("l")
controller.open('www.google.com')
```